# is anyone using credit link and credit link file together and linking to nodes AND Files

Tags: wysiwyg

I'm obviously missing something very simple. I installed ckedit link with [wysiwyg](https://www.drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) module and when selecting internal links I can select nodes.  Then I installed ckedit link file and internal links only allow me to link to files.  There must be a way to use internal links for nodes or files, but I can't seem to find it.